# Adding values from df to a longer df

Tags: r

I have two data frames of different lengths with the following variables:

df1: State, County, Income, Age

df2 (the longer one): Zip.Code, State, County

So that df1 has a unique entry for each combination of State & County, and df2 can have several of those for different zip codes.

I'm trying to assign income and age from df1 to each row (Zip.Code) in df2.
I've tried:

```
dplyr:: left_join(df2, df1, by=c("STATE", "COUNTY"))
```

or

```
df2$Income <- NA 
df2$Age <- NA

for (i in 1:length(df2$Zip.Code)){
  for (j in 1:length(df1$STATE)){
if (df2$STATE[i]== df1$STATE[j] & df2$COUNTY[i]== df1$COUNTY[j]){
df2$Age[i] <- df1$Age[j]
df2$Income[i] <- df1$Income[j]
 }
}}
```

The result of this is NA for all Income and Age.

UPDATE: the problem was different ways of writing states. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `dplyr::left_join(df2, df1, by = c("County", "State"))`.

Comment: also check out the `merge` function.

Comment: Should have mentioned it - left_join gets me the same results (NA)

Answer (score 0):

Use merge:

```
merge(df1,df2, by=c("County","State"))
```